# Scapy won't start

Tags: python, scapy

My Scapy v2.3.3 won't start. Fresh reinstalled Python 2.7, WinPcap10 and pyreadline. Sometimes it starts after at second try in the same console.

```
c:\Python27\Scripts>scapy

c:\Python27\Scripts>python c:\Python27\Scripts\scapy
INFO: Can't import matplotlib. Won't be able to plot.
INFO: Can't import PyX. Won't be able to use psdump() or pdfdump().
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python27\Scripts\scapy", line 26, in <module>
    interact()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\main.py", line 300, in interact
    scapy_builtins = __import__("all",globals(),locals(),".").__dict__
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\all.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scapy.arch import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\__init__.py", line 83, in <module>
    from scapy.arch.windows import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 318, in <module>
    IFACES.load_from_powershell()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 270, in load_from_powershell
    for i in get_windows_if_list():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 206, in get_windows_if_list
    for line in query)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 205, in <genexpr>
    (dict(zip(['name', 'win_index', 'description', 'guid', 'mac'], line))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scapy\arch\windows\__init__.py", line 53, in _exec_query_ps
    l.append(line.split(':', 1)[1].strip())
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: check your variable `line` the value you are expecting and you  are getting is not the same.

Comment: It's standard scapy files, i'm not responsible for its internals.

Comment: I mean I don't think it's a good idea to interfere with its.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug was implemented in [6840d30](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/commit/6840d30b5d197c6fd770fa1b0b3c710e7262498b) (v2.3.3) and fixed in [a454ef4](https://github.com/secdev/scapy/commit/a454ef48361e3786c416a1fe1af059d00fb88e02), it could be fixed by changing

```py
l.append(line.split(':', 1)[1].strip())
```

to

```py
 sl = line.split(':', 1)
 if len(sl) == 1:
     l[-1] += sl[0].strip()
     continue
 else:
     l.append(sl[1].strip())
```